# Как создать простой компилятор для простого языка (например, brainfuck)?

Tags: c++, компилятор, brainfuck

В общем хочу написать компилятор brainfuck или своего собственного языка (простого).
Как это сделать?   
P.S.
  Интерпретатор (для brainfuck) я осилил сам, как сделать компилятор я даже не догадываюсь.
Желательно найти литературу.

Answer (score 3):

для brainfuck я когда то сам писал компилятор. Лучше для начала написать траслятор, который переведет код в с/с++/java/любой другой любимый язык. Это очень просто. [Вот](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/116160/) пример траслятора в Java.
После того, как получится написать такое, никто не мешает написать похожее для ассеблера (для fasm или masm). Последней ступенькой будет генерирование сразу исполнимого файла. О том, что нужно знать ассемблер, я думаю вопросов нет.

И ещё немного интересного материала  - http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/development/113339/

Answer (score 3):

Есть такая книжка, Marc-André Cournoyer, «[How To Create Your Own Freaking Awesome Programming Language](http://createyourproglang.com/)» (по ссылке — продается, но ищущий название и слово "pdf" всегда найдет и где взять менее цивлизованно, ЕВПОЧЯ). Показывают основы на пальцах, этакая «Драконья Книга для самых маленьких». Начинают с лексера и парсера, затем интерпретатор, и затем — компилятор под LLVM и, на всякий случай, собственную игрушечную виртуальную машину. Все, правда, на Ruby, но общие идеи от языка не зависят. Так что если есть интерес — можете поискать и посмотреть, рекомендую.

Answer (score -1):

Было уже.

[Давайте создадим компилятор](http://kit.kulichki.net/crenshaw/tutor1.html)

Comment: тут используется pascal-я его плохо понимаю(тем-более на линукс его нет)

Comment: На линукс есть паскаль(free pascal compiler), но лучше не нужно.

Comment: вот именно